# Configure proxy setting for Chef client

Tags: chef-infra

I have `chef-client` cookbook in my run list. In my environment I have some proxy attributes. Something similar to

```
"chef_client": {
  "config": {
    "http_proxy": "http://proxy.com:3128",
    "https_proxy": "http://proxy.com:3128",
    "no_proxy": "*.mydomain.com, localhost"
  }
```

When I start the client manually after ssh to my machine these settings are not used it seems. So `sudo chef-client` does not seem to use these settings.

To fix this I opened `/etc/chef/client.rb` on the machine and added proxy settings.

Of course this is not the Chef way to configure a proxy server. How should I do this?

Comment: Use the config recipe of the cookbook wich will use this attributes to write the client.rb file.

Answer (score 2):

When bootstrap your node, then include --bootstrap-proxy option with your proxy in bootstrap command , this will add your proxy configuration in /etc/chef/client.rb file at client side.

Eg.

`knife bootstrap [NODE-IP] --sudo -x [USERNAME] -P [PASSWORD] -N [NODE NAME FOR CHEF SEVRER]  --bootstrap-proxy http://proxy.com:3128`